# How do I predict the spectrum when a magnetic field is applied on a specific transition from a term symbol to another?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

More specifically the question pertains to physical/quantum chemistry, and to the transition 2D (with J = 3/2) -> 2P (J = 1/2)
where the numbers before the letters are multiplicities (these are term symbols.) likely an application of the zeeman interaction, but I don't understand how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a weak magnetic field the $J$ levels are split into $m_j=\pm1/2$ for $J=1/2$ and $m_J= 3/2,1/2,-1/2,-3/2$ when $J=3/2$. Transitions between these $6$ levels follow the $\Delta m_J=0,\pm1$ selection rule.  As both states are doublets the $\Delta S=0$ selection rule is also satisfied and the $\Delta L=1$ also between P and D. The splitting between the $J=1/2$ and $J=3/2$ sub-levels (fine structure) is not quit the same so the spectrum should have six lines probably split into three sets of doublets.